# Selenium Grid +Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid

I am trying a `POC` on selenium grid. I am receiving this error :

> Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=47, platform=WIN8_1}]

Below is the code :

```
BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
        nodeURL="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setVersion("47");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8_1);
        extent = new ExtentReports("./extentReport.html",true,DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<path>\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),capabilities);
        //driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.qaonlinetraining.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I just did a small tweak.

1). I launched the command prompt in "admin mode". 
2). Gave the java path as "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java" in it 
3). Then ran the command as "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" without specifying any role

and **Vollaaaa...it got fixed...!!!**

**Thanks to all of you for your help...Was after this error for last 3 days...a great relief  must say.. :-)**

Checkout this link for more information on how to do this...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187314/7551276

Comment: Tried the same approach but no luck..have posted new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127728/selenium-grid-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-error-forwarding-the-new). Would love to hear thoughts

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to get rid of -role hub option while setting up the node. Look at the discussion in this link.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1226

Note: Launch the command prompt in admin mode.

Comment: I received another error
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

I tried with 2.46.0 , 2.48.2, 2.43.0 jars of selenium

Comment: I guess the initial error with grid is resolved. Now have you downloaded chromedriver correctly to the path you have mentioned in your code?

File file = new File("C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: I did that but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Selenium-server-standalone with below commands as hub and node.

For hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub
```

For node (Chrome):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxinstance=1,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a bit. Its not clear why and how.

Comment: I received another error FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html I tried with 2.46.0 , 2.48.2, 2.43.0 jars of selenium

Comment: I did this too.  File file = new File("C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe"); System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath()); But it didn't helped.

Comment: Supply chrome driver path while initiating the node like below. Edited my answer to reflect the same.   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -hub localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxinstance=1,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe

Answer (score -1):

For hub execute the command as
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 8080

For node execute the command as
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\program files\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://ipaddress:portnumber/grid/register -port 5556

To Remember (Do not specify the role for hub)