# Selenium Grid Extras 2.0.4 : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I tried to use Selenium Grid Extras from the page: https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras

I managed to use it successfully on my private machine. I ran the command "java -jar Selenium-Grid-Extras-Jar.jar" and after configuration (https://ibb.co/j4wZPH), I was able to see the nodes by going to the address http://localhost:4444/grid/console:

[image]

Then I ran the tests via IntellIj and everything passed as expected: [image]

But when I try to do the same process on my corporate laptop, I get the error:
[image]

I will attach full log of this error:

```
kwi 24, 2018 12:07:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session 
Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, version: }
Command duration or timeout: 157 milliseconds
<4 internal calls>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:145)
    at com.sii.BaseTest.RemoteWebdriverTestBaseDemoqa.setUp(RemoteWebdriverTestBaseDemoqa.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, version: }
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'BXKBFH2', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:118)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:86)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And when I go to: http://localhost:4444/grid/console - I see this: [image]

I tried to figure out why I get this error and found the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187314/7967616) that Selenium Grid doesn't have any node available with a browser that has the desired capabilities.

But during configuration I set the PORT 5555 for Selenium Grid Node and it works on my private laptop. I could not find the answer in the internet, so my hunch is that there is some problem with that PORT, but I don't know how I can check this.

Anyone had similar issues or problems or can help me with this issue?
Will be grateful for any help.

**EDITED**

ChromeDriver version is 2.38 (latest)

Chrome Browser version is 66.0.3359.117 (actual)

I made sure that I have latest version of ChromeDriver and Browser.

Comment: IMO, all the **crucial** and **relevant** _bytes_ & _bits_ are well hidden with the snapshots. Can you update the question with **text based** _code trials_ and _error trace logs_ for a better analysis?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you specify which specific code trial and error trace should I attach? I updated question and added error trace to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teammate helped me solve the problem. I had to unlock the ports in Windows Defender Firewall.

- Go to Windows Defender Firewall (Open as admin)
- Go to "Incoming rules"
- In section "Actions" add new Rule -> select Port -> Select:

  1. Once - TCP
  2. Secondly - UDP
- Provide ports (4444, 3000, 5555)
- Enable connection

Repeat the proces but:

- Go to "Leaving rules"
- In section "Actions" add new Rule -> select Port -> Select:

  1. Once - TCP
  2. Secondly - UDP
- Provide ports (4444, 3000, 5555)
- Enable connection

Reboot the system and set up the Selenium Grid Extras again. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Unlock selenium extras, hub and node ports in firewall and then it should work

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, version: }
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** wasn't able to initiate an active connection with the WebClient i.e **Chrome** browser.

In absence of *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeBrowser* versioning information it seems to be **version compatibility** issue between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *chromedriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *chrome* version is unknown to us.

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: I edited my question. I have latest version of Chrome Driver and Browser. Should I anyway use CCleaner and do remaining steps like rebuilding the project (which I did) and rebooting the system (which I did)?

Comment: Steps 3-6 should be part of _Best Practices_ before and after your _Test Execution_. Update the question with your _Hub_, _Node_ starting commands, _current code block_ and _error stack trace_ please.

Comment: @JeyKey Upvote this/any answer which is/was useful to you for the future readers.